# Does the 'reads' column in SQL Profiler mean the same as IOPS?

Tags: sql-server, profiler

I just executed a query that went pretty fast and the SQL Profiler said it used 30.000 reads.
Now I'm looking at this page: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance and see that a standard persistent disk has 3000 reads IOPS.

Does that mean that my query would take 10 seconds when run there? Or does `SQL reads` and `read IOPS` mean a totally different thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One "read" in Profiler simply equates to reading one 8kb page.

This does not equate to IOPS, nor does it necessarily mean that data was read from disk. When performing a read, SQL Server will read data from disk only if that page does not already exist in the buffer cache. All data passes through the buffer cache before being used to satisfy your query.

Therefore, you can think of this number as not having anything to do with disk IO, but instead being a measure of the amount of data read from memory.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Reads are when SQL analyzes a disk block. The block could have 10 records or 100 records within it. The amount of reads can be determined how the query is written. [Past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738836/what-is-logical-reads-in-sql-server-how-to-reduce-no-of-logical) example. It's possible to have zero physical reads because the data is in memory.

IOPS are the amount of input and output read and writes that can be performed a second.

> Most storage vendors perform their IOPS measurements using a 4k block size, which is irrelevant for SQL Server workloads; remember that SQL Server reads data 64k at a time (mostly).
>
> IOPS and throughput are a measurement of activity, but there’s no measure of timeliness involved. Latency is a measure of timeliness, but it’s devoid of speed.
>
> Combining IOPS, throughput, and latency numbers is a step in the right direction. It lets us combine activity (IOPS), throughput (MB/s), and performance (latency) to examine system performance.

[Reference](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/09/iops-are-a-scam/)

So I would not say that 30,000 SQL Server Physical reads on a 3000 reads IOPS disk will equal 10 seconds, there are many more environmental factors at play.